# Vue.js SSR - how to require vue-server-renderer with import instead?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I **require** `vue-server-renderer` with `import` instead?

```
const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer()
```

I tried:

```
import renderer from 'vue-server-renderer'
const vueRenderer = renderer.createRenderer()
```

Error:

```
var vueRenderer = _vueServerRenderer2.default.createRenderer();
                                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRenderer' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createRenderer` - export function in package `vue-server-renderer`

```
import {createRenderer} from 'vue-server-renderer'

const renderer = createRenderer()
```