# Why can I not access a function through an instance of a package using import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I am trying to use ES6 imports and am running into a problem with `vue-server-renderer`. It is [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785200/vue-js-ssr-how-to-require-vue-server-renderer-with-import-instead) but not quite the same.

I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createBundleRenderer' of undefined` when I run this:

```
import vueServerRenderer from 'vue-server-renderer'
const createRenderer = (serverBundle) =>
    vueServerRenderer.createBundleRenderer(serverBundle, {
        runInNewContext: false,
        template: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, indexFolder,'index.html'), 'utf-8')
    });
```

But if I do the following, then no error:

```
import {createBundleRenderer} from 'vue-server-renderer'
const createRenderer = (serverBundle) =>
    createBundleRenderer(serverBundle, {
        runInNewContext: false,
        template: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, indexFolder,'index.html'), 'utf-8')
    });
```

Why do I have to import the function directly from vue-server-renderer? What is wrong with accessing it through an instance of vue-server-renderer using `vueServerRenderer.createBundleRenderer()` instead of just `createBundleRenderer()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is quite simple, If you will go to  'vue-server-renderer' you will get {createBundleRenderer}  as an export member.

If you want to use like

```
import vueServerRenderer from 'vue-server-renderer'
const createRenderer = (serverBundle) =>
    vueServerRenderer.createBundleRenderer(serverBundle, {
        runInNewContext: false,
        template: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, indexFolder,'index.html'), 'utf-8')
    });
```

Some mistake is there related to import, you should import like 
`import * as vueServerRenderer from 'vue-server-renderer'`
It should surely work for you

Comment: How do I find out which functions are being exported by a package? Do I need to go into node modules?

Comment: not really you don't need to do that because if you will look into the express package it has exported as express everything. something like export.module = express;
but in case if we need a specific function we use to get llike
`import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';`
so It totally up to library there is not standards

Comment: but to be safe, there is no harm in doing `import * as` for all my packages right?

Comment: to be honest I will suggest using module import like ` import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';` because it makes less imports and code gets cleaner