# How do you find out which functions are exported by a node/npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, node-modules

Following my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838796/why-can-i-not-access-a-function-through-an-instance-of-a-package-using-import/61838887), and the Mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) on `import`, I now understand that I must do something like the following to use the functionality in a module:

1. `import * as name from "module";` or
2. `import {functionName} from "module";`

Coming from using CommonJS, I never thought about which functions were exported by a package because I just used to `require` them like:

```
const vueServerRenderer = require('vue-server-renderer') // get the module
vueServerRenderer.createRenderer() // use a function in that module
```

How can someone find out which functions are being exported by a module such as `express` or `vueServerRenderer` so I know how to use the correct `import` statement like:

`import express from 'express'` instead of `import * as express from 'express'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the module source.

Every `export` statement exports something. It may be a function, an array, a string, a class etc.

Every `export` statement without `default` needs to be destructured on import:

```
import { NonDefaultThing1, NonDefaultThing2 } from 'somewhere'
```

An `export` statement with `default` must be imported directly without the `{}`:

```
import DefaultThing from 'somewhere'
```

Some modules have default export but also non-default exports. You can pick and choose what to import:

```
import DefaultThing, { NonDefaultThing7 } from 'somewhere'
```

If you use an IDE that can parse javascript such as Microsoft [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) you can get autocompletion/intellisense of the `import` statement. There are even plugins that does auto-import: just use a class or function or something from a module and it will automatically add the required import statement at the top of your file.

Comment: thank you ill see if IntelliJ Idea has such functionality. i think it does

Comment: Why does `import * as express from 'express'` not work but`import express from 'express'` does? If I do `import *...` and then `app = express()` I get an error saying express is not a function. Why? I thought the * imports everything?

Answer (score -2):

TLDR: The `default` export.

Say a particular library named "module" has the following code

```js
function functionName() {
  // function body
}

export default functionName;
```

Now, in your code, if you put

```js
import blah from "module";
```

then `blah` will point to `functionName`.

Comment: Okay, but how do you find out that `module` even has `export default functionName`? Some modules don't have export default at all and only export specific functions.

Comment: Then you cannot use just the `import` statement like this. In such a situation, you should use the following syntax.
```import {funcitonName} from 'module';```

Comment: The other answer is what I was looking for. The only way to tell *what* is available in the export is to look at the module source code or use an IDE with intellisense